# String walking throws exception in VS2005 C++

Tags: c++, string, stl, visual-studio-2005

I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2005 (large legacy project).

Have the following code snippet:

```
bool FOO::bar(const string& input_text)
{

  string::const_iterator
        ch = input_text.begin(),
        last_ch = input_text.end();

  for( ; ch!=last_ch; ++ch )
  {  
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        const char a = *ch;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  }
  return true;
}
```

When I run this code in debug mode it crashes on the `const char a = *ch` line and says:

Unhandled exception at 0x0000000140d08b20 in foobar.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

When I run this code in release mode, it runs just fine.

This code is called as follows:

```
CString full_filter;
full_filter.Format( "*%s*", filter_value );
foo.bar((LPCTSTR)full_filter));
```

I am a VS2005 C++ novice, so am looking up what these mean now, but put this in due to questions in comments section.

I have found a number of seemingly related C questions and answers about this.  Based on those, I have tried defining various values for input_text, such as removing it from the parameters and just defining it as

`string input_text("FOO");`
or
`string input_text = "FOO";`
or
`char[] tmp = "FOO"; string input_text = tmp;`

All have failed.

I  have also taken the above code snippet and put it into it's own brand spanking new VS2005 project, and it runs just fine.

So, there are some .... unique settings in the legacy VS2005 project that are causing problems.  Any clue what those settings might possibly be, or how to smoke them out?  I'm a rank VS2005 novice.

Comment: this code can not crash like that... do you have threads? can you show how you use this?

Comment: what your error means is that it is trying to read from a pointer that isn't pointing to anything...

Comment: I ran this code and can confirm this does NOT crash. The problem must somehow be in how you use it.

Comment: how is bar called? maybe it is called on temporary that is no longer valid? maybe you have macro defined for ch - with some strange null pointer?

Comment: @neagoegab and thus the question!

Comment: I have added some more notes/results/thoughts....

Comment: How is the code called in the "legacy" project?

Comment: @Borgleader Added calling code above...

Comment: What is the type of `filter_value`?

Comment: why do you use Format with %s and not += ? what is the type of `filter_value`